# Why Google Chrome warns that a function could not be optimized because of a ForIn loop?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have an enterprise javascript web application where I utilize the for-in loop a lot. When I profiled the application at a potential bottleneck, Chrome profiler gave me lots of exclamation mark icons next to function names, and alerted that those functions were not optimized due to ForIn loop.

The profiled code had many functions using for-in loop, also in recursion.

I couldn't find any related material on the internet about this. Why these loops affect performance? How to work it around? Can it really be a bottleneck?

Comment: The for-in syntax in itself is a part of the language spec and should not be creating any performance issues merely by using it. It all comes down to the object you are iterating over, how you are iterating over it, and what happens in each iteration. If you post some code people might be able to help

Comment: For..in loops iterate over the properties of an object *and its ancestors*, climbing up the prototype chain. That may be the cause of the warning.

Comment: Thanks but Chrome did not warn about bad performance, it stated that it could not optimize the function because of it (the message was something like "ForIn loop is slow", cannot tell now, but will update tomorrow to make the question more proper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn more about optimization of For-In loops, at the following link

[Optimization killers in Node.js](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#5-for-in)

It is the same case for google chrome javascript, Node.js and Chrome implements V8 Javascript engine

Comment: Wow, this article was definetaly helpful. I think in my case I'm referencing the field variable in lower scopes too, probably that's the issue, will try tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using loop like

```
for(var prop in myobj){
}
```

The reason chrome assumes it becuase, the for in loop will loop all the methods internal native properties and some of the property which is in accessible similar we see in the google chrome console

that could be the reason

Comment: Thanks, but I'm always using it with a local variable. (I'm using TypeScript, so I'm even forced to write it like that.)